# Controlling the fontsize across multiple browsers

Tags: browser

I've got 3 browsers on my Windows XP Pro: Firefox `3.5.2`, Opera 10 and IE 7. All pages are displayed fine in FF. Opera and IE seem to have a very similar issue: Both upsize fonts even though zoom mode in both browsers is set to 100%.

I tend to believe that this might be a system-wide setting, somewhere. Does anyone know this problem?

Comment: Upsize to what degree, and on what sites?  It is possible to be a website problem if the font size is very similar.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with browser font-size is discussed in this article "[Size Matters](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sizematters)".

If you're coding web pages you can fix it by using percentage fonts (ie font-size:150%;) or absolute keywords (font-size: small;) in your style sheet and the hack described in the article.

Answer (score 0):

Do Opera and IE maybe adhere to Windows' DPI setting, while Firefox does not? Not everything is displayed with 96 dpi ...